# Getting "This device does not exist" while using android management API

Tags: google-api, android-management-api

After removing the work profile and re-adding it again, the api returns "device does not exist".
Is this an intended message or is it just a bug on google's side?

Answer (score 0):

The error "The device does not exist." usually means that the deviceID you are using to call the API is not recognized by the server (i.e. incorrect device ID is being used, or the device was deleted using [enterprises.devices.delete](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/delete)).

Removing a work profile and re-adding it should not return Error 404: "The device does not exist.". However, the server would generate a new device name after re-adding the work profile on the device.